# JSF page isn't rerendered after failover

Tags: ajax, richfaces, cluster-computing, jsf-1.2, failover

We have a little problem with our application when it's deployed in cluster. After we shutdown the working node, session is restored on another one and application keeps working but we need to either refresh the page entirely or move to another page because the page that was opened when server was shutdown just doesn't want to work correctly. It still sends requests, managed bean's methods are called and all data is correct but after AJAX request it doesn't want to rerender its parts. So the only thing we can do on the page is click on a link and move to another page because in this case we have GET request. How to fix it?

Comment: I would check responses from server to POST requests in firebug/devtools, it should generate html/xml to replace parts of the page, check if the responses looks alright (compare with responses before node shutdown). It might be so that auto-generated ids are different, so RichFaces cannot find elemement with the id to replace in DOM.

Comment: I checked responses and they are different indeed: second response (after failover) doesn't contain some of the parts that should be replaced and auto-generated ids are really different. So the problem is not only in new auto-generated ids but also in abscence of a lot of elements in new response. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: I think you can create a page and specify ids on every element, so there are no auto-generated ids, and check if the use case works OK for that scenario. If it does - it seems there is a problem how jsf generates ids, it might be so that something crucial is not put to session, so it is lost after session replication.